# after usort a array , string key change to num key?

Tags: php, arrays, usort

my php code is:

```
<?php
    $arr = array(
        'a' => array(
            'name' => 'aaa',
            'pos' => 2
        ),
        'b' => array(
            'name' => 'bbb',
            'pos' => 1
        )
    );
    var_dump($arr);
    function func_sort($a, $b) {
        return intval($a['pos']) - intval($b['pos']);
    }
    usort($arr, 'func_sort');
    var_dump($arr);
?>
```

the result is:

```
array(2) {
  ["a"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "aaa"
    ["pos"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  ["b"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "bbb"
    ["pos"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}


array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "bbb"
    ["pos"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "aaa"
    ["pos"]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
```

after usrot,string key change to num key,who can tell me why? and how to sort an array(with string key) but keep string key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) does that: it's the documented behaviour of the function, see the second `Note` on the docs page

if you need to maintain key associativity, use [uasort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)